# How to add bias variable in Keras with functional api without subclassing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried the following approaches:

```
import tensorflow as tf
inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,))

# first approach:
bias = tf.Variable(0., shape=(), trainable=True) # <= no parameters in the model

# second approach:
#bias = tf.Variable(0., shape=(1,), trainable=True) # <= error

# third approach:
#bias = tf.Variable(0., shape=(tf.shape(inp),), trainable=True) # <= error

outputs = inp + bias

# fourth approach:
#bias = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(1,1)
#outputs = inp + bias(0) # <= no parameters in the model

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
input = tf.random.uniform([1], dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.random.uniform([1], dtype=tf.float32)
model.fit(input, labels)
print(model.summary())
```

Neither of them working.
How can I add bias with fuctional API without subclassing ?

Comment: A [Dense layer implements a bias](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/). Would it suffice? Otherwise, it might doable to track an extra variable, but not worth the hassle IMHO.

Comment: It doesn't suffice because I don't know a shape of the input. Real case is more difficult than this toy example. I edited the question accordingly. I tried to track extra variables (refer to the example) - but didn't manage to do it

Comment: And what is the reason to not do a subclass? Keras is not really made for low level modifications, mayber you should consider native TensorFlow.

Comment: I am working with colab TPU, but it saves only p5, which saves only weights for subclassed models. I need to save optimizer state. Saving optimizer weights separately is not reliable.